# How do I verify my second-hand phone is 'clean'

Tags: security

I have just bought a second-hand Android phone (Samsung) and would like to check that there's nothing nasty on there before I start using it in earnest. It's my first smartphone! I have some experience with Linux Mint, but not a lot.

I've compiled a list of the apps installed (not system apps) and I would like to understand the origin of each and, on a superficial level at least, the purpose of each. I'm finding it hard to find some of this info, e.g. what is 'OM Customize'. Is there a good encyclopedia of Android apps out there that I've missed so far? I could post the list here if anyone can help?

The phone was very cheap, and I'm wondering whether there's some security tool I should use to check it, and potentially whether I should look at rooting it. My main usage at the moment is actually just going to be as a GPS tool and note-taker, so not particularly interested in the 'normal' bells and whistles applications.

[image: apps list]

Comment: If you're afraid of "left-overs", I'd simply [flash a fresh ROM](/tags/rom-flashing/info) (stock or custom). Though there could be things in the underlying, closed-source levels (e.g. baseband), those are rather "rare" (and hard to achive by a user, and unlikely to happen in drive-by mode).

Comment: I have worked in networks and security for a telephone company for a long time, one of the things we deal with on a regular basis are cell phones... In all my years of experience, we have never seen someone buy a phone deliberately tampered with to do anything for the new owner, nor I have ever heard that story from any other associates I have in this business in North America. The very few stories we have heard of this happening have all been based in Asia. My advice is perform a factory reset prior to setting it up, even if the previous owner did that, and you are 99.999% likely to be fine.

Comment: Thank you both, and I guess you saw nothing of concern in the app list above either. My mind is at rest. Any recommendations for Package Disabler or similar, more now that I want to cut down on traffic than the security aspect?